# How can I send an exception manually with Crittercism?

Tags: android, exception, crittercism

I'm using the android crittercism library and trying to send a report when I catched an error level exception.

But I can't find the documentation on how to do that. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please elaborate why you downvoted. It kinde sucks if I get a downvote without an explanation. I have no chance in removing the error if I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They temporarily moved the feature into beta. If you e-mail support they'll enable your account for handled exceptions. Below is the sample Android code:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Exception Reason");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Crittercism.logHandledException(exception);
}
```

Just in case you need it, here is sample code on iOS:

```
@try {
    [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException
            format:@"Foo must not be nil"];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    // Pass it on to us!
    [Crittercism logHandledException:exception]
}
```

Comment: do you know the maximum size of the string you can use in association with the exception? i.e. if i want to upload a report, like a file with many lines to a particular crash.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve same using "new relic" ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm the co-founder and CTO of [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com).  If you send me an awesome email, I can enable it for your account.  I'm rob[at] :)

Comment: I'm glad to see the CTO is so hands on with questions from his user base. (But this should probably have been a comment in the original post.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Crittercism.logHandledException(new Throwable("test"));
```

You don't actually have to throw the `Exception` (or `Throwable`, in this case).
It will appear under "Handled Exceptions" on Crittercism website.